# Showing legends for unselected plots in dropdown menu for Multiplot with dropdown Button

Tags: button, dropdown

I have a multi-plot created based on Jaydeep Mistry’s work on kaggle.com 1.
[Plotly] How to change plot data using dropdowns | Kaggle

What I would like is when I select any column from drop-down menu, currently only one legend shows up highlighted for a drop-down item. I would like legends for other columns also appear although in backlit state so that they can be added to the plot on as needed basis.

Problem with using “All” option from drop-down is there may be too many columns in the plot and then one has to click on many legends to remove them from the plot.

Can someone assist here? Thanks!

No idea how to proceed